# How to reload current R script file with a command?

Tags: r, rstudio

How to reload current R script file with a command after it has been changed by another program?

## edit:

Assume there is an initial file called test.R with following content:

```
1 # a random number

y <- readLines("test.R") # read the script

x <- as.numeric(y[1]) # convert the number to numeric
x <- x + 1 # increase the number by 1
y[1] <- x # assign the value to y
print(y[1]) 
writeLines(y, "test.R") # replace the old file by the new file
```

and now I would like to reload the current file such that the content is updated within the file itself. Since a couple of years RStudio has a reloading feature, but I cannot wait until RStudio's update signal is triggered. I want to trigger it myself.
This is relevant because I would like to write a R function which generates a table of content automatically for [xaringan](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan).

linked question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797227/table-of-contents-on-xaringan-slides/57190718#57190718).

Comment: Not sure what it is you want. .rs.restartR() will restart the Rstudio session? When you edit your script in for instance notepad++ it will automatically update in Rstudio?

Comment: Hey, thx. No I do not talk about restarting the session. Yes I am aware of Rstudio's reloading function but this is not triggered when you are in `xaringan`'s infinite_moon_reader mode

Answer (score 0):

Best I can do is

```
document_reload <- function() {
  path <- rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path
  rstudioapi::documentClose()
  shell(path)
}

document_reload()
```